# Entity translation not working

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I'm using Entity Metadata Wrapper and Entity Translation to programatically add a translation to existing nodes. This is my code, i'ts not working and I'm at loss to understand why:

```
$meta = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

$new_lang = 'fr';

$meta->language($new_lang);

$meta->language($new_lang)->title = 'Some French Title';

// Other fields are changed, but not shown here

$r = $meta->value();

$handler = entity_translation_get_handler('node',$r);

$translation = array(
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'nid'         => $node->nid,
  'uid'         => $node->uid,
  'created'     => $node->created,
  'changed'     => $node->changed,
  'translate'   => 1,
  'status'      => 1,
  'language'    => $new_lang,
  'source'      => $node->language,
);

$handler->setTranslation($translation, $r);

$meta->save();
```

Comment: Any news on this? Did you manage to solve it? Did you get a chance to try my suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Most importantly, you should be calling `$handler->saveTranslations();` after setting the translation. Your updated code should look like this:

```
$meta = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

$new_lang = 'fr';

$meta->language($new_lang);

// The body field is set to be translatable.
$meta->language($new_lang)->body->value = 'Some French Body';

// Other fields are changed, but not shown here

$handler = entity_translation_get_handler('node',$node);
$translations = $handler->getTranslations();

// This is a convenience way to initialize the translation data for
// the new language.
$new_translation = array(
  'language' => $new_lang,
  'source' => $translations->original
) + $translations->data[$translations->original];

$handler->setTranslation($new_translation);
$handler->saveTranslations();
$meta->save();
```

As a last note, the `title` property of a node is not translatable, unless you use the [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module. In that case, you should probably use the `$meta->title_field` accessor to change the value.

Good luck!